# Type of constant in "unsigned ux = 2147483648;"

Tags: c, constants, unsigned, signed

If I write this declaration:

```
unsigned ux = 2147483648;
```

(2<sup>31</sup>), will the C compiler treat 2147483648 as an unsigned or signed value?

I've heard that constant values are always treated as signed, but I don't think that's always right.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: If you are worried, use the `U` suffix specifier for the value: `unsigned ux=2147483648U;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of an unsuffixed decimal constant such as `2147483648` depends on the value of the constant, the ranges of the predefined type, and, in some cases on the version of the C standard you're using.

In C89/C90, the type is the first of:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `unsigned long int`

in which it fits.

In C99 and later, it's the first of:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `long long int`

in which it fits.

You didn't tell us what implementation you're using, but if `long int` is 32 bits on your system, then `2147483648` will be of type `unsigned long int` if you have a pre-C99 compiler, or (signed) `long long int` if you have a C99 or later compiler.

But in your particular case:

```
unsigned ux = 2147483648;
```

it doesn't matter.  If the constant is of type `unsigned int`, then it's already of the right type, and no conversion is necessary.  If it's of type `long long int` (as it must be in C99 or later, given 32-bit `long`), then the value must be converted from that type to `unsigned`.  Conversion from a signed type to an unsigned type is well defined.

So if `unsigned` is wide enough to represent the value `2147483648`, then that's the value that will be stored in `ux`.  And if it isn't (if `unsigned int` is 16 bits, for example), then the conversion will result in `0` being stored in `ux`.

You can exercise some control over the type of a constant by appending a suffix to it.  For example, `2147483648UL` is guaranteed to be of some unsigned type (it could be either `unsigned int` or `unsigned long int`).

Incidentally, your question's title is currently "About Class Cast.(if I write unsigned ux=2147483648(2 to the 31 st))", but your question has nothing to do with classes (which don't exist in C) or with casts.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thanks,Keith.Your answer is pretty great and elaborate enough.Thank you. By the way, I have to tell you that I am a Chinese University Student,so maybe I made a wrong english translation about "cast",I don't tell the difference between two words:"cast" and controversion".Thank you again~!

Comment: @FreeMind: A "conversion" is an operation that converts a value of one type to some other type.  A "cast" is an explicit operator, such as `(int)x`, that specifies a conversion.  (A lot of people confuse them.)